# Inputtext invoke javascript function get error

Tags: javascript, events, primefaces, onkeyup

I would like to call function on backingbean only if the user press the `enter` key. But it doesn't work. On Chrome's console, it's always returns: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` everytime I press any button. What's wrong with the code? Thanks.

```
<p:inputText id="txtValue" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" onkeyup="onkeypress()">
</p:inputText>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onkeypress() {
        if(event.keyCode==13) {
            alert("true");
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
    }
</script>
<p:remoteCommand name="rc" actionListener="#{cc.onKeyPress}" out="count" />
```

Comment: You've to rename your function, like `keyPress()`. `onkeypress()` is another eventhandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add parameter to your `onkeypress` function would fix your problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onkeypress(event) {
        if(event.keyCode==13) {
            alert("true");
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it should be like: `if(event==13) {...` and on the html: `... onkeyup="onkeypress(event.keyCode)">`.. :)